# Open Source .NET Desktop UI Frameworks

Tags: c#, open-source

Are there any open source frameworks to help build a .NET GUI?

I would also be fine with free frameworks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few of them.

Most of the larger ones are [listed here](http://mono-project.com/Gui_Toolkits).

Answer (score 3):

[OpenWinforms](http://feeds.feedburner.com/Openwinforms) has a variety of open source controls and some various articles.

If you are just looking for some free controls, the [Krypton Toolkit](https://github.com/ComponentFactory/Krypton) is a really nice library has a free library of a lot of common controls, but no source is available.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, definitely - if you plan on using WPF/Silverlight, please do take a look at [Caliburn](http://www.codeplex.com/caliburn) - it's a lean framework for WPF and Silverlight GUI development.

It has some nice features for IoC container integration, and it supports various patterns that are good practice when writing view code - e.g. the command pattern is pretty nifty.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [patterns & practices - Smart Client Guidance](http://smartclient.codeplex.com/) or any other [patterns & practices project](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?TagName=patterns%20%26%20practices) from Microsoft.
They are nice if you going to write a enterprise application, for a small hobby project they might be a bit oversized.